# CMake fails to execute cxxtestgen

Tags: c++, cmake, cxxtest

I'm trying the following CMake cmakelist.txt file for executing tests for my school project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(ex2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/bin/g++-5")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wextra -Wall -std=c++11")

find_package(CxxTest)
if(CXXTEST_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
    enable_testing()
    CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(bag_of_words_runner tests/bag_of_words_runner.cpp tests/BagOfWordsTests.h)
    CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(parsing_runner tests/parsing_runner.cpp tests/ParsingTests.h)
    target_link_libraries(bag_of_words_runner ex2)
    target_link_libraries(parsing_runner ex2)
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES MIR.cpp SongEntry.cpp BagOfWords.cpp Parameters.cpp parsing)
add_executable(ex2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

But I get following error:

```
luftzug$ cmake --build /Users/luftzug/Library/Caches/clion11/cmake/generated/c7799756/c7799756/Debug --target bag_of_words_runner -- -j 4[ 33%] Generating tests/bag_of_words_runner.cpp
  File "/usr/local/bin/cxxtestgen", line 2
    PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/cxxtest/4.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/cxxtest/4.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/cxxtest/4.4/libexec/bin/cxxtestgen" "$@"
                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make[3]: *** [tests/bag_of_words_runner.cpp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bag_of_words_runner.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bag_of_words_runner.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [bag_of_words_runner] Error 2
```

I had tried running it outside of CLion just to rule that out.
I can run cxxtestgen from the command line with no trouble at all.

Any idea or a workaround? I need to be able to run these unit tests, preferably from using CMake (to enjoy the benefits of it's integration with CLion).

Answer (score 0):

It happens that FindCxxTest thought `/usr/local/bin/cxxtestgen` is a python script. However it is not; maybe previously it was. The cmake module is not yet up to date. Here's a temporary fix:

```
find_package(CxxTest)
set(CXXTEST_TESTGEN_INTERPRETER bash)  # FindCxxTest module bug
CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(...)
```